# Simplification of $n^{1/\sqrt{\log n}}$

Tags: functions, exponentiation

I would like to simplify this function, how can we do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You may write, for $n >1$,

> $$
> n^{1/\sqrt{\log n}}=e^{\log n/\sqrt{\log n}}=e^{\sqrt{\log n}}
> $$

using
$$
a^b=e^{b \log a}, \qquad a>0, \,b>0.
$$

Comment: @Dingo13 Ok, thanks!

Comment: Is it completely obvious that $n^{1/k}$ dominates $e^{(\log n)^{1/k}}$ ?

Comment: If $X>k$ then $\frac{X}k>X^{1/k}$. That is $n^{1/k}=e^{(\log n)/k}$ dominates $e^{(\log n)^{1/k}}$ for $\log n >k$.

Comment: Thanks very much. How we prove that if $X>k$ then $X/k> X^{1/k}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$$n=e^{\log n}$$

$$n^{1/(\log n)^{1/2}} =e^{(\log n)^{1/2}}$$